# how can i change button color in unity 3D C#?

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine, colors

i have 2 buttons "A" and "B" .
on clicking button "A" i want to **change the color** of button "B"
scripting in C# any help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the event called when your A button is clicked, use a reference to your B button to get his image component and change the color of it. The following code should work:

```
bButton.GetComponent<Image>().color = yourColor;
```

If you only want to work on the button itself, you can also define a [ColorBlock](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ColorBlock.html), fill it with the previous color properties of your Button, and change it's [normalColor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ColorBlock-normalColor.html) component before setting it on your button:

```
ColorBlock colorBlock = bButton.GetComponent<Button>().colors;
colorBlock.normalColor = yourColor;
bButton.GetComponent<Button>().colors = colorBlock;
```

Comment: thanks for your time i tried this but background of the button (white) instead of turning red it disappeared.

Comment: @AwaisChaudhry Which solution did you try?

Comment: Now it worked thanks i used 2nd, can you do me just one more favor, how can i change it further on clicks,like on first click **Red** second click **Blue** 3rd click **Green** and on 4th click again **Red** and repeat again.. i am new to unity C# , @lsuka

Comment: @AwaisChaudhry When asking something different, you should open a different question, except if you can already find the answer elsewhere on Internet or on Stack Overflow. Anyway, as we are in it, I'll help you. :)
You can store those 3 colors in a List<Color> object (let's call it listColor), and save which index (currentIndex) in the list you are currently using (0, 1 or 2). Then when you push the A button, ask `colorBlock.normalColor` to be equal to `listColor[currentIndex]`, and then increment your index by 1 while using a modulo 3 on it. Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change the background color of the button. This should work. Replace the Red for the color you want

```
    private void buttonA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       buttonB.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

Comment: Error : " button does not contain defination of BackColor "

Comment: put a snippet of your code

Comment: There is no `BackColor` property anywhere in Unity. I guess you mean `buttonB.color` with _buttonB_ being an **Image** component?